# str object has no attribute strftime

Tags: python

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

```
if __name__=="__main__":

    df=pd.read_excel("abhi.xlsx")
    #print(df)
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m")
    yearNow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
    #print(type(today))
    writeInd =[]
    for index, item in df.iterrows():
        print(index,item['Birthday'])

        pr_bday = item['Birthday'].strftime("%d-%m")
        print(pr_bday)
```

Comment: Yes, your `item['Birthday']` is a string, while `strftime` is a method of `datetime` class, so you can't call it on that object.

Comment: first you have to convert `string` to `datetime` using `datetime.datetime.strptime(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Because your column 'Birthday' is not datetime type, actually it is a string type object.
You can use `df.dtype` to check type of each column in df.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html

Or you can just use `type(item['Birthday'])` to get the type directly.

Comment: Actually I have make error in excel date time format.After change the excel Birthday col.now program ok.before-18/05/2020 when i change this 18/05/2020 21:00:00 then its work and return the output